# How to prevent Opera Turbo compression

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have a site (running Apache and PHP) that allows users to download JPEGs. The user clicks once on a link to download the JPEG, the same as when you download a zip file (not using right-click save-as).

The PHP script that handles the download add these headers:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.jpg');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_final));
```

Opera users, with the Opera Turbo feature switched on, are having a problem.

Instead of getting the JPEGs, they get files that have been compressed by Opera's server. (I think they are WebP images, they begin with `RIFFÞÃ  WEBPVP8`). They appear the same in the browser, but when user downloads them to their desktop, they can't use them.

How can I configure my web server to prevent Opera Turbo from compressing JPEGs? Is there a HTTP header I can send?

Comment: This is a user problem. They obviously missed the right-click menu item that says "Reload image in full quality."

Comment: The user does not have that option as it is a download link for an image. I've updated the question.